# Set PackageId at package time?

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, nuget-package

I'm trying to figure out how to specify a packageId at build or specifically at package time. I have the following in my csproj which works well for creating packages locally for the purposes of testing. We are using Azure DevOps build pipelines to build and pack our nuget packages and I would like to be able to set the packageId as a task or msbuild parameter within the build pipeline.

Does anyone have suggestions on how I could acheive this?

Thanks,

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
        <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
        <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
        <TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>$(TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput);Dependencies</TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>
        <Version>0.1.0.5</Version>
        <PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>true</PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>
        <AssemblyName>MyAssembly</AssemblyName>
        <RootNamespace>MyAssembly</RootNamespace>
        <AssemblyVersion>1.0.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
        <PackageId>MyAssembly.Test</PackageId>          <----- set at package time
        <FileVersion>1.0.0.0</FileVersion>
        <PackageLicenseUrl>https://my.domain.xyz/license.pdf</PackageLicenseUrl>
        <AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>True</AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>
        <Description>A useful description.</Description>
        <Company>XYZ</Company>
        <Authors>UiPath</Authors>
        <PackageIconUrl>http://my.domain.xyz/favicon.ico</PackageIconUrl>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Set PackageId at package time?

The answer is yes.

According to the document [MSBuild pack target inputs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#pack-target-inputs), we could to know the `PackageId` is supported to be set at build time.

**Note:**

I saw that you set the property `GeneratePackageOnBuild` to `true`, so visual studio will generate the nuget package automatically.

So, if you are not use extra `dotnet pack` task to package your package, you add msbuild argument `-p:PackageId=<PackageId>` with your dotnet build task, like:

```
dotnet build -c Release -p:PackageId=<PackageId>
```

If you have another `dotnet pack` task to package your package, @Martin`s answer is correct.

**Note2:**

When we use the option `-p:PackageId` to change the package ID, but the AssemblyName is not changed. So the `Package ID` of the generated package is not consistent with its `AssemblyName`. We need to pay more attention when we use this nuget package. Or we could also change the `AssemblyName` to make it match the package id by the option `-p:AssemblyName=<AssemblyName>`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try calling?:

```
dotnet pack -c Release -p:PackageId=The.Other.Packge.id
```

Or the equivalent in the .NET Core CLI task

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the XML of the csproj after clone and before build using the File Transform task:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/file-transform?view=azure-devops

Comment: Thanks James, I was not aware of the file transform util and this will come in handy in the future.